# No configuration could be found for a session named 'dummy'

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I have created a new session under staging in mongoid.yml as:

```
staging:
  sessions:
    dummy:
      database: dummy_db
      hosts:
        - ipaddress:27017
    default:
      database: "dummy_db2"
      hosts:
        - 127.0.0.1:27017
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false
```

And accessing two mongo instances using this method. But its giving error

```
Mongoid::Errors::NoSessionConfig: 
Problem: No configuration could be found for a session named 'dummy'
```

on runtime. Its working fine for default case.. but couldn't find dummy session.

Here is my mongo class

```
module Mongo
  class test
    include Mongoid::Document
    store_in session: 'dummy'
```

Please help anyone.

Comment: Are you sure you're running server in `staging` environment?

Comment: @nattfodd yes server is on staging environment